# Kaggle Notebook Session Disconnect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am training a deep learning model on Kaggle with GPU, the training will take many hours, during training I have to leave the system and close the browser to get some work done but doing so closes the Kaggle session after 40  minutes and When I reopen the notebook a pop up display that should I continue editing after clicking yes the session starts agin. How I can make sure my kaggle notebook won't stop even I close the browser.